# Android: FloatingActionButton leads to "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

I have a floating button in a fragment and wants to pass intent to another activity. However, when I press the floating button, it leads to "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error.

Below is the logcat:

> > 01-29 15:51:07.361 5909-5909/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment.CreateContactListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
> >                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3155)
> >                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
> >                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> >                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
> >                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> >                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
> >                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
> >                                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
> >                                                                                                        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
> >                                                                                                        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:164)
> >                                                                                                        at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment.CreateContactListActivity.onCreate(CreateContactListActivity.java:45)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3263) 
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
> >                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> >                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
> >                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897) 
> >                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> >                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
> >                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
> >                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

This is my xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/plannerLinearLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvContactsCategories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAddConList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

-----------------EDIT-------------------

Below are my codes for the intent:

```
 FloatingActionButton fab;
 fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabAddConList);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent createContactList = new Intent(context, CreateContactListActivity.class);
                createContactList.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(createContactList);
            }
        });
```

Comment: post your Activity too

Comment: As per logcat you are not passing String message to println() method

Comment: Or are you doing any `Log.d(ex.getMessage())`? As ex.getMessage() might give you NPE.

Comment: Your error clearly says that you have null pointer at Log

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same error as here:
[How to startActivity using actionbar item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287336/how-to-startactivity-using-actionbar-item)

See this line in your logcat:

```
com.example.l33902.contactmanagment.CreateContactListActivity.onCreate(CreateContactListActivity.java:45)
```

It states you have an error in *CreateContactListActivity.java* on line 45.